# CSS Tooltip has different position in different browsers. How can I account for this?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, tooltip

I have adjusted my bottom attribute to display how I want it in Firefox, but the spacing is all warped in Chrome and Safari. Is there a way to sett a different "top" attribute for each browser?

HTML

```
    <a class="tooltip" href="#"> <!-- this tag activates my tool tip -->
<div class="handsevent" >    <!-- this div contains everything that activates the tool tip when hovered over-->
    <div class="handswrapper">    
        <div class="handshour" >
            <h3>8:00am-noon</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="handsspeaker">
            <h3>Speaker 3</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="handstitle">
         <p>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
    <span class="classic">   <!-- this span contains everything that pops up in the tool tip -->
        <h3>Title Bar</h3>
        <br />lots of descriptive text
    </span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
/* HOVER WINDOW */
.tooltip {
color: #000000; outline: none; font-style:bold;
cursor: help; text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
}
.tooltip span {
margin-left: -999em;
position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
border-radius: 30px 30px; -moz-border-radius: 30px; -webkit-border-radius: 30px; 
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
position: auto; left: 1em; top: 2em; z-index: 99; <!-- the 'top' attribute on this line is where I have been adjusting the display position it affects the position differently in different browsers -->
margin-left: 0; width: 700px; margin-top:-10px;
}
.tooltip:hover img {
border: 0; margin: -30px 0 0 90px;
float: right; position:fixed; 
z-index: 99;
}
.tooltip:hover em {
font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight: bold; color:005DA4;
display: block; padding: -0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
}
.classic { padding: 0.8em 1em; }
* html a:hover { background: transparent; }
.classic {background: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #ffffff; }
```

I have tried pixels, em, and percentage. None of these have been consistent. Are there browser specific settings I could use?

[here is a demo link for reference.](http://experimentswithawesomeness.com/RandomHosting/HandsOn_test.html#)

Comment: have you looked at qtip2? link: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Comment: I had, but I am not familiar with JQUERY or Javascript in my web applications and it seems to be a bit over my head. I was hoping to avoid it if possible. If this is the best method though, I suppose its time to run through the codecademy course, get familiar, and figure it out. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: QTip2 is rather strange. I got it to work only when I set it to a subdiv and hover on the parent. When I set it to the parent and hover the parent, it displays blank. Even then, it does not work quite how I want it. I'm going to stick to straight CSS for now, but I'll come back to it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switch the top attribute in ".tooltip:hover span" to "auto" and that seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) will help to eliminate differences between browsers.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was trying to work out Qtips, but its giving me some trouble. I tried all the versions on the front page of your link and a couple others but they do not seem to be having an effect on my issue. I've read it is a best practice to customize them yourself, but I am not sure how to do that. 

I switch the top attribute in ".tooltip:hover span" to "auto" and that seems to be working. I have another essentially identical code that uses 'bottom' instead of 'top' which this fix did not work for. I suppose that is another issue though. 

Thank you for the help.